# Join regular expressions for line ranges in sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have the following code that finds all `<p> </ p>` within the label `<TXT_accesp> </TXT_accesp>` and delete them. This code does that, it works correctly:

```
find /home -type f -name "*.html" -exec \
    sed -i '/\<TXT_accesp\>/,/\<\/TXT_accesp\>/s@</\?p>@@g' {} \;
```

The problem is that I need to add more labels. Now you must delete all `<p> </ p>` that is within `<TXT_accesp> </TXT_accesp>` or within `<TXT_acceng> </TXT_acceng>` but I can not join the regular expression OR, I get an error (that the command does not exist, as if badly done).

```
find /home -type f -name "*.html" -exec \
    sed -i '/\<TXT_accesp\>/,/\<\/TXT_accesp\>\||\<TXT_acceng\>/,/\<\/TXT_acceng\>/s@</\?p>‌​@@g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` does not support alternation (OR or `||`) between ranges of lines. Some versions support extended regexes with alternation in the regex, but what you need here is two commands to `sed` with the `-e` option (for readability):

```
find /home -type f -name "*.html" -exec \
    sed -i -e '/\<TXT_accesp\>/,/\<\/TXT_accesp\>/s@</\?p>@@g' \
           -e '/\<TXT_acceng\>/,/\<\/TXT_acceng\>/s@</\?p>@@g' \
        {} \;
```

You can collapse that onto one line; you should not do so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Finally, the code has been as follows:

`find /home -type f -name "*.html" -exec \
    sed -i -e '/<TXT_accesp>/,/<\/TXT_accesp>/s@</\?p>@@g' \
           -e '/<TXT_acceng>/,/<\/TXT_acceng>/s@</\?p>@@g' \
        {} \;`